# I can't open cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

It was always normal of Cassandra, but today when I go to bin folder of cassandra and run `./cassandra`, there isn't any response, just go into a new command line and no that opening process. And I can't open cqlsh, either. Could you help me solve this issue?

system.log shows the only error:

```
ERROR [main] 2017-08-07 10:33:59,154 CassandraDaemon.java:655 - Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed) 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)           
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]           
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375) ~[na:1.8.0_141]           
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.RMIServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(RMIServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:33) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]           
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666) ~[na:1.8.0_141]     
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:330) ~[na:1.8.0_141]       
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:249) ~[na:1.8.0_141]       
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411) ~[na:1.8.0_141]       
at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[na:1.8.0_141]       
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:236) ~[na:1.8.0_141]       
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:213) ~[na:1.8.0_141]       
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:173) ~[na:1.8.0_141]       
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:144) ~[na:1.8.0_141]       
at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:239) ~[na:1.8.0_141]       
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:119) [apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]       
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188) [apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]       
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:533) [apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]       
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:642) [apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
```

Comment: check system.log for any errors

Comment: I have added the error in the question, but I think maybe it's that problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems like port are already in use.
You can kill process as below

```
sudo fuser -n tcp 7199
```

It will show all process id of running on that port.
You can kill using below command.

```
sudo kill -9 Pid
```

Now start Cassandra. it will start.

Comment: find like **ps ax|grep cassandra** and kill that process id.

Comment: root@srv-machine-learning01:~# ps ax|grep cassandra                           
845 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep cassandra
root@srv-machine-learning01:~# kill -9 845                                              -bash: kill (845) - No such process

Comment: Can please provide bit more information like operating system are you using?

Comment: Sure,    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: https://gist.github.com/marcosvidolin/df5debc68e45314780a8 this might help you to kill process on port

Comment: all the process of cassandra have been killed, but I still can't run command `./cassandra`, no response

Comment: The port 7199 is perhaps used by another process than Cassandra. But in that case, you might prefer change the JMX port used by Cassandra to avoid conflict rather than killing the other process. Then check Aaron answer to configure the JMX port.

Answer (score 0):

If something is legitimately using the default JMX port (7199) you can change the port that Cassandra uses for JMX quite easily.  Look for the `JMX_PORT` line in the `cassandra-env.sh` file, and change it to a port that you know isn't being used:

```
JMX_PORT="7199"
```

to:

```
JMX_PORT="9455"
```

Eliminate that port conflict, and see if Cassandra will start then.